# re-run of .net build when using teamcity

Tags: .net, build, teamcity

I am trying to setup a .net build using Teamcity. We got it to compile and now the problem is once started it keeps building in a loop. Is there a setting I can do to get rid of the multiple runs in Teamcity.

I ran the MSbuild from command line using the same solution (.sln) file it works ok and runs only once.

Thanks In advance

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "Build Triggering" settings in the build configuration for your project (in Team City).

Comment: I have paused the build and No build triggers are set Still if I start the build manually it keeps building. I have to stop manually

Comment: The problem was resolved. It was due to dependency config in Teamcity.